# could not execute a file generated by php from terminal

Tags: command-line

I am trying to execute a file from terminal generated by PHP.
When i manually type the file, its executing the perfect. But when it is generated by PHP program, it throws an error.

The permission of both files are same.

I have attached image with error in terminal.
The code is related to import of MySQL database to ElasticSearch Cluster.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for trailing spaces after the terminal backslashes `\`.

There should not be any!

Comment: Yes, I did that, file comparision, its 100% match. still couldnt

Comment: windows endline then, reopen file with gedit and save with LInux/UNIX endline

Comment: I am linux environment.

Answer (score 1):

If the permissions are indeed the same, run this:

```
diff -c normal.script php-output.script
```

File names are self explanatory I believe.